# What are the rules for Tower targeting in Smite?

Tags: xbox-one, smite

How do towers (and pheonixes and titans etc) decide when to attack minions vs gods when both are in range?

I've personally seen several scenarios where towers ignore minions in favor of gods, when the minions are closer to the tower and attacking it. Other times, I've seen towers attack archers while 4 or 5 gods melee the tower.

I've also been targeted by a tower while I fought another god in the tower circle, even though friendly gods and minions were attacking that tower at the same time, at a much closer range.

I previously thought towers preferred minions before gods. Then I thought it attacked the most healthy enemy within range. Then I thought it attacked maybe the enemy with the highest damage potential, or highest kills, but these all seem to be proven wrong in one situation or another.

Is there a solid rule for their behavior? I'm on console but i assume this isn't platform-specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a tower picks a target, it picks the closest minion within range of the tower first, or the closest god to the tower if there are no minions.

Once a target is acquired, the tower will focus fire that target until it is dead or leaves tower range, at which point the tower will pick a new target, except in one case.

If the tower is targeting a minion, and an enemy god within range of the tower damages an allied god, then the tower will change targets to the enemy god that dealt the damage. In this way, the tower protects allied gods.

If you're going to dive, it's a good idea to have your tankiest ally deal damage first, so he can get the tower aggro, and then the other allied gods who dive in will be safe until the tank leaves range or dies.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense and seems to explain the things I've seen happen. I'll accept this when the timer completes,  but is there a source for this info?  i couldn't find it on the wiki

Comment: @Dpeif Not terribly official, but [here](https://smiteworld.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/smite-glossary/)'s at least one corroborating internet site. This is a fairly standard way for tower aggro to work in MOBA games. I know LoL works the same way.

Comment: works for me, link much appreciated! i didn't know a lot of that stuff

Comment: This is easily testable in lieu of online sources. Co-op mode is a great mode to test stuff in.

Comment: With LoL, for the aggro to change to a champion, the allied champion must be in range of the tower as well as the attacking champion. Do you know if this is the case for Smite?